# Get Lun numbers and corresponding names - windows

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I have a list of  names of luns including mountpoints. I am looking to find the corresponding lun numbers/ disk numbers (The same which we see on disk management) by programming

```
Disk 0  C:
Disk 1  D:
```

Any hints please  - looking to do this through powershell

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824136/61396

Comment: im trying to run the script posted by Chad Miller in the thread, but it is failing - wonder why

Answer (score 4):

I would look into using WMI to get this information.  A good place to look is in Win32_diskdrive.

```
$Drives = gwmi Win32_diskdrive
```